# switching yes-no images using jquery when clicked on it

Tags: jquery, html, image, onclick, attr

I wrote a code that switches an image from Yes to No using jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    $('#s-ref').click(function(){
        $("#s-img").attr('src',"no.png");
    });
});
```

html is:

```
<a href="#" id="s-ref"><img src="yes.png" alt="" id="s-img"></a>
```

How to modify the jQuery code above so that it switches back and force (yes/no/yes/no/yes...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the img src...

```
$(function() {
    $('#s-ref').click(function(){
        if ($("#s-img").attr('src') == 'yes.png')
          $("#s-img").attr('src',"no.png");
        else
          $("#s-img").attr('src',"yes.png");
    });
});
```

Or... This would work if the scr contained 'yes.png' for example '/foo/barr/yes.png:

```
$(function() {
    $('#s-ref').click(function(){
        if ($('#s-img[src*="yes.png"]').length > 0)
          $("#s-img").attr('src',"no.png");
        else
          $("#s-img").attr('src',"yes.png");
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle to illustrate the latter answer - http://jsfiddle.net/nz35B/